# Reveal a View / Button on next swipe, when RecyclerView is scrolled to it's end

Tags: android, animation

I would like to achieve kind of the same animation as Google in it's Lollipop Dialer. Unfortunately it seems to be closed source.

Please have a look at the following animation:
[image]

1) The first swipe scrolls the RecyclerView to it's first item, while showing the standard "this is the end of the list"-animation.

2) The second swipe reveals the extra button with a beautiful animation at the top.

How can I achieve this as well?
Do I need the MotionEvent?